# Upgrade my laptop does not start now, I return to login

Tags: linux

Hi I have a problem with my Kali linux, Yesterday I did a upgrade in my kali and after of this I restart my laptop, now the problem is that when I put the user and password everything is correct just that return to login and never enters the graphical interface. try to login with another interface with the i3 and not work, it always returns to the user login of kali and the password and user is correct.

Comment: Just to be sure: login with root / toor doesn't work? Try login with terminal (ctrl +alt +f1) or ssh from another pc. If that doesn't work, boot in rescue mode from grub. Then check that your /tmp folder has these permissions 'drwxrwxrwt' and owner root:root. If that doesn't work try sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.old

Comment: thanks for your answer, try everything you told me and I still can not access my laptop

Comment: Is your username listed in /etc/passwd ? If you can login via terminal or rescue mode, you can reset your password via the terminal (passwd {username}). You can also re-install the graphical shell: sudo apt-get purge gdm3 && sudo apt-get install gdm3

Comment: yes I did it nad dont work

Comment: I'm at a loss here. Last resort: check the log files for any clues (/var/log/gdm, /var/log/security and /var/log/messages). Without more info I can't help you.